# Object has value but properties inside don't have - angular

Tags: angular

I have this code

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { Message } from '../models/message';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message',
  templateUrl: './message.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message.component.css']
})
export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() message: Message;
  sender: string;
  body: string;
  createdAt: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(message = this.message) {

    this.sender = message.Sender;
    this.body = message.Body;
    this.createdAt = message.CreatedAt;
    console.log(message);
    console.log(message.Sender);
    console.log(message.Body);
    console.log(message.CreatedAt);
    console.log(this.sender);
    console.log(this.body);
    console.log(this.createdAt);
  }
}
```

`message` has value which you can see in the image below.. but when you look at its properties specifically, it is undefined.

[image: error image]

This undefined properties is why my component is not rendering anything..

EDIT:
Here is my `Message` class.

```
export class Message {
  Id: number;
  Body: string;
  CreatedAt: string;
  Sender: string;
}
```

Comment: try printing `message["body"];`

Comment: it seems that even though my class has upper case on first letter javascript uses small letters while being run.

Comment: this is Angular, property start with lower letter. you should use this way: `public var:string; public yourVarTypedInThisWay:string;`

Comment: Yes you are right. What a headache. Kind of used to upper case on properties because of `c#`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this properties start with simple letters

```
console.log(message.sender);
console.log(message.body);
console.log(message.createdAt);
```

Comment: Correct, it's case sensitive!

Comment: Wow! But why? my model has upper case on first letter.. but when it was run it seems it was compiled as lower case on first letter. Changed the model's properties to lower case and it runs smoothly..